# Integrating QlikView with SimPro

Tags: qlikview

Has anyone ever tried to integrate QlikView BI application with SimPro business management software? If so, would be interested to know if you were successful and if so how?!!

Answer (score 0):

Dorey.

Jonathan from simPRO here.

I'm not aware of any clients that have an integration with QlikView but it is a well respected reporting platform with a myriad of ways to extract data from other systems.

A quick scout around their documentation tells me that the easiest option for integration would using their QVSource API connector.

Details are here: http://www.qvsource.com/Connectors-For-QlikView/General-JSON-XML-SOAP-Web-API-Connector-For-QlikView

For simPROs API you would use this in "POST" methodology - ie: supplying the post data as per our API docs at: http://api.simpro.co . Our API uses OAuth authentication and there is dome detail and examples on using that with QVsource at: http://wiki.qvsource.com/General-Web-Connector-For-QlikView.ashx

Whilst we may not be able assist technically with setting up the QlikView system our technical support department can assist with any queries you have in regards to our API calls etc...

Hope that is of some help!

Comment: Jonathan. I really appreciate your response - it is definitely the most comprehensive response I have received from SimPro regarding my dilemma. All I really want to do is get access to my data within SimPro and I am struggling to get information on how to do this. I am not a programmer and would really like to avoid the expense of having to use one, so is there any simple way for me to use the API to get my information even into a simple file format where I can then write my own reports?

Comment: Hi there.

Sure - understand your dilemma.

Although in this instance the API is probably not going to be your best option - as with any API these are designed usually for programmatic interaction.

The are lots of ways we could potentially provide what you need - but I'd need to know what sort of things you want to report on etc... that way we can help come up with a solution.

Maybe we could book a call sometime late this week and you can take me through what it is you want to extract report on - and I'll see where we can help get you that data.

Let me know what suits.

Comment: Jonathan, thank you for your response. I would really appreciate a discussion with you on this matter. I am in the office all day Thursday if that suits. Guess it will be morning UK time as you on Australia time?!

Answer (score 0):

I am going to try and respond to your dilemma, while being a QV expert for the last 8 years I am not too familiar with simpro, however I did quickly browse through their API docs here -> http://api.simpro.co/

I have noticed that they support 3 formats, namely soap, json and xml. For qlikview you would choose xml. I have also noticed that they support 2 authentication methods namely basic auth and O Auth. IN this scenario you would be using basic auth (so you can pass a username and password via the url) as this will also work perfectly with Qlikview.

In your Edit Script, you will notice a "Data from files"-> Web Files, then in the popup you can enter the url from where you would retrieve your information from.

Note you need to pass format=xml to the url, along with your basic auth username and password to the relevant url (which you will find in simpro's docs), for any other format you will need QVSource which has a fee attached.

I hope this has pointed you in the right direction.